# removing unnecessary and repetitive patterns from R object and changing to standard time format

Tags: r, time

I am working on an email data set including 3 columns as sender, receiver and time of communication, I must constrain emails data to working hour, but the problem is that the time format is like this *2017-03-27T02:06:42.793Z*
so i wonder how i can i convert this format to a normal time format as *%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S*, to be able to constrain the time.

I also test the following:

> email$time2= format(anytime(email$time), "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

but strangely this command adds one hour to each corresponding time; i mean for instance *"2017-03-27T00:00:37.820Z"* *has converted to "17-03-27 01:00:37"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trailing characters are ignored so that could be read with only a slight variation in your format string:

```
 as.POSIXct("2017-03-27T02:06:42.793Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",
             tz="America/Los_Angeles")
[1] "2017-03-27 02:06:42 PDT"
```

Comment: thanks it works this way.  i also have to add that for constraining the data based on time i used lubricate package as follows:  
 `df_time_constraint= with( df , df[ hour( df$time ) >= 7 & hour( df$time ) < 20 , ] )`